# FME doesn´t accept my ArcGIS 10.3.1 Installation as being current

Tags: arcgis-10.3, fme-form, arcgis-license-manager

When creating a lasd file with fme I get the following error although I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 installed

> FME has checked out an Esri license. The product checked out is
>   'ArcInfo'
>
> LAS writer: ArcGIS 10.1 or newer is required to create an ArcGIS LAS
>   Dataset.  No ArcGIS LAS Dataset will be created.  LAS files produced
>   by the FME LAS writer have not been affected

Is there anyone who has defeated this error?

Comment: try running fme 'as administrator'

Comment: What level of licencing do you have on the desktop?  Do you have any extensions?

Comment: Advanced licence with 3d analyst, spatial analyst, network analyst, and a few others... xtoolspro/et geowizards

Comment: Is it possible someone else has the license checked out? Is ArcGIS running anything at the time you're running your workbench (not sure if this matters)? Are your extensions enabled (just asking)?

Comment: What version of FME are you running?

Comment: Edition: FME ESRI Edition (node locked-crc)
Version: FME(R) 2016.0.1.0 (20160130 - Build 16174 - WIN64)

Comment: I've asked our developers at Safe to check this and I will get back to you. I don't see any known incompatibility with FME2016 and ArcGIS 10.3.1 (it's not like you're running FME2012 or anything), so right now I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ArcGIS Pro? Does it mention that in the log file? We're wondering if the version number of ArcGIS Pro is causing confusion with the reader/writer.

If that's the case, a workaround might be to install the optional package for ArcGIS Desktop for 64-bit Background Geoprocessing.  The ArcObjects from that 64-bit ArcGIS Desktop will be chosen before anything from ArcGIS Pro.

If that's not the case, or doesn't help, then I'd suggest [contacting our support team](http://safe.com/support) and filing a case, since it could be more complex than we can cover here.

Comment: I *think* "ArcObjects from ArcGIS Pro" may be loose terminology.  From https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/FAQ: "**Is the ArcGIS Pro SDK similar to ArcObjects and COM extensions?** There are many familiar patterns such as buttons (commands), tools, sketch or construction tools, dockpanes, menus, and menu items. There are new patterns, too, such as galleries, split buttons, split tools, extensions (via add-in modules), and ribbons. However, the new SDK is not ArcObjects; therefore, existing ArcObjects code needs to be redeveloped."  If I'm wrong, I'm keen to know.

Comment: I do have ArcGIS Pro installed on my system. I'll try your suggestions with 64-bit Background processing and let you know if it helps.

Comment: @PolyGeo - You're correct. The SDK you mention is not ArcObjects.